# AWS CDK : Why S3 bucket policy occurs error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I try to deploy S3 bucket by CDK in TypeScript. When the code is executed, an error occurs even if I have a privilige of administrator. Anyone knows the reason?

```
export class S3Stack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const s3Example = new s3.Bucket(this, 'bucket', {
      versioned: false,
      bucketName: 'bucket',
      publicReadAccess: false,
      blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
    });

    const s3ExamplePolicyDocument = {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "FirstStatement",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "s3:List*",
            "s3:Get*"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
          ],
          "Principal": "*",
        }
      ]
    };

    const s3ExamplePolicy = iam.PolicyDocument.fromJson(s3ExamplePolicyDocument);

    new s3.CfnBucketPolicy(this, 'bucketpolicy', {
      bucket: s3Example.bucketName,
      policyDocument: s3ExamplePolicy
    });
  }
}
```

Error message

```
API: s3:PutBucketPolicy Access Denied
```

Comment: I presume you are running a command like `cdk deploy --profile test PipelineStack`. Did you check whether you have the right permissions for the credentials you are using in the profile?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. This is caused because I try to apply public permission to non-public bucket. After I modified s3ExamplePolicyDocument, it works

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you modified s3ExamplePolicyBucket